# Drawing routes on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to draw routes with google maps or any other map api? Like when you're looking for direction from point a to point b on google map with `Get Directions` button.

I'd like to draw a line that follows certain road but without the directions I don't need those. And if I can draw multiple lines between multiple points on the map that would be awesome.

Has anyone had experience with this before?

Comment: [Example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or, if you really prefer to ignore the directions Google generates, you can use the [maps API drawing functions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) to draw your own lines on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can also employ "drawing library"
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing

But,this experimental tool cant specify colors nor line-thick via GUI.
My enhanced example is at:
http://members.jcom.home.ne.jp/tcltk-d/ge-navi.html
(select "Drawing" view to draw)